# Performance wise is better to use a split or a matching regex to extract subtext from a string?

Tags: java, regex, performance, split

I have a string like this:

```
/good/312321312/bad/3213122131
```

I have to extract the two sets of digits from there.
I thought about two solutions: either using the `split()` or simply writing a regex to match the digits.
What would be the better solution performance wise?
If you have any other suggestion please tell me so.

Comment: Its better to not to speculate on performance, and only look at specific issues if they appear, remembering that different JDK implementations can dramatically change some tasks anyway.  `String.split()` does have a shortcut implementation for certain simple one or two character inputs, otherwise it delegates to regex. So for many apps there isn't a difference, and for other apps you may well not be able to tell the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a split approach *might* typically be the more efficient approach.  We can split the input into components and then check each one to see if it be an long integer.

```java
String path = "/good/312321312/bad/3213122131";
String[] parts = path.split("/");
List<Long> nums = new ArrayList<>();
for (String part : parts) {
    try {
        long num = Long.parseLong(part);
        nums.add(num);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
}

System.out.println("Found nums: " + nums);
```

This prints:

```
Found nums: [312321312, 3213122131]
```

Any solution which only uses base string functions might outperform the cost of invoking a regex engine.

Comment: Thanks! It is possible to check if a string contains another string in a case insensitive manner without using a regex engine?

Comment: @gutey Yes: Use my approach above along with `String#equalsIgnoreCase()` to check for a string in a case insensitive manner.

Comment: However equals is for identical strings. Is there something like `String#containsIgnoreCase()`?

Comment: Just use `part.toLowerCase().contains("valuetofindinlowercase")`

Comment: No other way? I need necessarily to lowerCase the string? Eventually I'll make a new question later.

Comment: I have answered all your questions.  Maybe you should open a new question.

Comment: Sorry for -1, but that's an awful solution. Your suggested code actually works 10-20 times [*slower*](https://gist.github.com/apangin/e110744a5b589433be86265b864e0624) than a regex equivalent due to the huge overhead of exception throwing.

Comment: Hmm...did you actually benchmark my solution against regex, or do you just "think" you're right?

Comment: Both. My above link points to the benchmark with the results. Besides that, it's a know fact ([1](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/exceptional-performance/), [2](https://vimeo.com/233820012#t=289)) that exceptions are very expensive and should not be used in a normal non-exceptional control flow.

Answer (score 2):

Since creating a new string implies copying all characters, the implicit `substring` operations of `split` are the most expensive aspect here. Creating an array, to hold all the strings, adds to it, but is minuscule compared to the string creations. Still, we can avoid both.

```java
static final Pattern NUMBER = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "/good/312321312/bad/3213122131";

    long first = -1, second = -1;
    Matcher m = NUMBER.matcher(s);
    if(m.find()) {
        first = Long.parseLong(s, m.start(), m.end(), 10);
        if(m.find()) {
            second = Long.parseLong(s, m.start(), m.end(), 10);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(first + "\t" + second);
}
```

or

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "/good/312321312/bad/3213122131";

    LongStream.Builder b = LongStream.builder();
    Matcher m = NUMBER.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) b.add(Long.parseLong(s, m.start(), m.end(), 10));

    long[] result = b.build().toArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```

When performance matters, it’s important to keep and reuse compiled `Pattern` instances instead of using convenience methods like [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) which throw away the `Pattern` instance after the operation.

Obviously, this only matters if the code is executed more than once. But when the code is executed only once, its performance wouldn’t matter anyway.

The [`Long.parseLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.CharSequence,int,int,int)) method that allows to skip the `substring` operation exists since Java 9. But even when you use `Long.parseLong(m.group())` here, you avoid creating strings for the non-numerical parts and retain the temporary strings as short as possible, which is optimizer-friendly.